# Alter the browser URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, request, rails-routing

Is there any way to change the browser URL of the request?
Lets say I've a `'/articles/foo-bar'` and I need to change this to `'/articles/foo_bar'`.

I've tried Routing Constraints and changed the `request.path_info` with no luck. I successfully changed the parameters but is not reflected in Browser URL.

PS: I want to replace '-' to '_' in browser URL in overall App.

EDITED:

Routes: `get 'brands/:name-:id/articles', to: 'brands#articles'`

Here `name` can be changed dynamically. And if a dash in `name` should be replaced by underscore.

Comment: Do you want something like `match '/articles/foo_bar', :to => 'articles#some_method_name', :via => :post or :get`

Comment: @Abhi No, I want to change dash to underscore (like using gsub) whenever a dash exists in the Browser URL. And `'/articles/foo_bar'` and `'/articles/foo-bar'` is already redirecting to same controller's action. So I just want to change the browser URL.

Comment: What I understand, you want `http://something/articles/foo_bar` instead of `http://something/articles/foo-bar`. So, for this you can try custom routing as I suggested above

Comment: This foo-bar is dynamic. I've added my routes in question. Please check.

Comment: Check if [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints) helps

Comment: No. This will allow the URL that fulfill the constraints. But how do I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use to_params method on your model
Please check this
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails